# Shared Elements Transition between 2 similar fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I'm trying to create a transition between 2 fragments. Login and SignUp.

They have many similar elements. Email, Password, the button, the title.

The extra elements in SignUp are Agree to terms, and repeat password.

I tried adding all of these as shared elements, but the only transition that is happening is the `ChangeBounds` transition on the LinearLayout that is holding all these elements.

I tried `AutoTransition()` and postponing the animation using

```kotlin
postponeEnterTransition()
(view.parent as View?)?.doOnPreDraw {
    startPostponedEnterTransition()
}
```

But that makes the UI freeze until the other fragment is fully drawn.

I'm also using Navigation Component, though that shouldn't make much difference.

What am I missing? Is there something I'm supposed to do that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Are you applying transitionName to both source and destination views? make sure they are unique for each view

Comment: yes, I recall that both the source and destination views should have same transitionName? Or is it unique between source and destination?